# JPA in JSF-Converter

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jpa, architecture

Is it the right way to use an entitymanager in a JSF-Converter?

Or is it better to set only the Id-Attribute(s) and let the viewbean calls the Entitymanager (or a service with an Entitymanager)?

The converter is used for a selectOneMenu. But I do not know how to implement a solution, I want to know, what is the better / cleaner way to do this.

Comment: Could you please add, for which situation you need a JSF-Converter? For example do you got a `<h:selectOne/>` component that can contain different entities?

Comment: You are right, i need the converter for a selectOneMenu

Comment: I want to know what is the better and cleaner way, not the implementation of an genericEntityConverter

Comment: *"The converter is used for a selectOneMenu"* I'd say best way is to not convert via JPA but via f:selectItems.

Answer (score 0):

In general software should be developed in multiple layers ([Multilayered Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayered_architecture)). Therefore a service which calls the entity manager to retrieve your objects is always a good way ([SoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)). Especially when you need access to the objects from multiple places ([DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)).